# Odd and Even border of list won't work

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm using the theme here http://demo.theme.co/ethos-1/

My goal is to have the square post previews round(succeeded) and have a border that alternates in color every other list item.

But for some reason my odd and even css is not working.

I've tried being more specific on my selectors but have not found one that gets it to work.

I've uploaded the following relevant code:

```
    /*

Theme Name: X &ndash; Child Theme
Theme URI: http://theme.co/x/
Author: Themeco
Author URI: http://theme.co/
Description: Make all of your modifications to X in this child theme.
Version: 1.0.0
Template: x

*/

.entry-cover {
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 95%;
}
.entry-cover:nth-child(2n+1) {
   border:5px solid black;
}
.entry-cover:nth-child(2n) {
   border:5px solid red;
}
.x-navbar-wrap {
    margin-top: 3.5%;
}
.slick-list.draggable {
    margin-top: 1%;
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a closer look at the structure of your page. All `.entry-cover` elements will always be a *first child* since they are always inside `li>article>a.entry-cover`. You want to put the even/odd selectors on the `li.x-post-carousel-item` instead.

Comment: When I use that it effects the square border not the round one

Comment: @Paulie_D I get that. But sometimes in order to replicate a problem you need to see the whole site. As something that might not seem so relevant could be effecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your CSS and see magic like this. [it's look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1k0G.png)

```
.slick-track li:nth-child(odd) article a {
    width: 230px;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    height: 230px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid red !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    background-size: cover;
}

.slick-track li:nth-child(even) article a {
    width: 230px;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    height: 230px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid green !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    background-size: cover;
}

.h-entry-cover {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% - 6em);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.5em;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.615s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
    transition: all 0.615s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]This css seems to work as hsan mentioned your CSS selector is incorrect. Also would use **even** / **odd**

```
li.x-post-carousel-item:nth-child(even) {
   border:5px solid black;
}
li.x-post-carousel-item:nth-child(odd) {
   border:5px solid red;
}
```

If you want everything rounded with odd borders you need to go a step further:

```
.entry-cover {
  border-radius:100%;
}
.x-post-carousel.unstyled .entry-cover{
  border:none !important;
}
li.x-post-carousel-item {
    border-radius: 95%;
    width: 95%;
}
li.x-post-carousel-item:nth-child(even) {
   border:5px solid black;
}
li.x-post-carousel-item:nth-child(odd) {
   border:5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: i was about to write this :)

Answer (score 2):

Try including `x-post-carousel-item` class like this:

```
.entry-cover {
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 95%;
}
.x-post-carousel-item:nth-child(2n+1) .entry-cover {
   border:5px solid black;
}
.x-post-carousel-item:nth-child(2n) .entry-cover {
   border:5px solid red;
}
.x-navbar-wrap {
    margin-top: 3.5%;
}
.slick-list.draggable {
    margin-top: 1%;
}
```

Please note that there is no need to use `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

You are try with wrong css class. Because `.entry-cover` is a child of `li` tag, so that your css not working. Use `li` tag for odd and even css.
Like this:

```
.entry-cover {
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 95%;
}
.x-post-carousel-item:nth-child(odd) .entry-cover {
   border:5px solid black;
}
.x-post-carousel-item:nth-child(even) .entry-cover {
   border:5px solid red;
}
.x-navbar-wrap {
    margin-top: 3.5%;
}
.slick-list.draggable {
    margin-top: 1%;
}
```